# Codename One ComboBox how to highlighting already selected value

Tags: codenameone

We are able to create ComboBox and populating data too. But we need to highlighting already saved values. Can you please suggest code for this.

Our requirement is if Combobox has 1,2,3. If I select 2 and save. We need to set the combo box value 2 in such way that when we open the Combobox need to display this 2 as highlight value along with 1,2,3 values.

Simply same as select box option selection.

Answer (score 0):

I would generally [recommend avoiding ComboBox](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-dont-use-combobox.html) altogether.

Assuming this isn't an option you will need to define a renderer and disable the OS specific 2 render mode using a [theme constant](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html):

```
otherPopupRendererBool=false
```